# How to fix animation bug when using setContentOffset in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

In my current project I have a collectionView that has 2 cells. The width and the height of the first cell equals the iphones screen height and width. In the bottom I a have a customized navigation bar with 2 icons. When I use:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: screenWidth, y: 0)
collectionView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
```

the animation works fine but for me its a little bit too slow. But when I use:

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
     self.collectionView.setContentOffset(point, animated: false)
 })
```

then the first cell does not move out of the screen (to the left) like in the first animation instead it just disappears instantly and the then the second cell moves into the screen from the right.

Has anyone an idea why the first cell disappears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only **two cells**, you may be better off (for several reasons) making them views in a scroll view.

However, if you want to stick with your two-cell collection view...

When you tell UIKit to animate the `.contentOffset` change, UIKit will figure out *what needs to be displayed* at the end of the animation.

Because you are scrolling a cell completely out-of-view, UIKit decides it doesn't need to manage that cell during the animation.

One solution is to set the `.contentOffset.x` to **one-point *less*** than needed, and then "finish" the positioning in the completion block of the animation.

So...

If we're going from cell `0` to cell `1` (sliding from right to left):

- animate to `x: screenWidth - 1.0`
- set `.contentOffset.x = screenWidth` in the completion

If we're going from cell `1` to cell `0` (sliding from left to right):

- animate to `x: 1.0`
- set `.contentOffset.x = 0.0` in the completion

Sample code:

```
func animateToFirstCell() {
    var point: CGPoint = .init(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.collectionView.setContentOffset(point, animated: false)
    }, completion: { _ in
        point.x = 0.0
        self.collectionView.setContentOffset(point, animated: false)
    })
}
func animateToSecondCell() {
    var point: CGPoint = .init(x: screenWidth - 1.0, y: 0.0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.collectionView.setContentOffset(point, animated: false)
    }, completion: { _ in
        point.x = self.screenWidth
        self.collectionView.setContentOffset(point, animated: false)
    })
}
```

---

**Edit**

Some benefits of `UICollectionView`:

- flow (or custom) layout
- memory management - allows a LARGE number of cells
- cell / item selection

If you only have two "full-view cells" that you're switching between, so you're not using any of the other benefits of a collection view, you may find it much easier to put two views in a scroll view.

Among the advantages of that approach includes the fact that your views ("cells") are not being removed/added every time you scroll back and forth.

Here's a quick example...

Instead of a `UICollectionViewCell` we'll use a `UIView` subclass:

```
class ViewInsteadOfCell: UIView {
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.textColor = .black
        return v
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        addSubview(theLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            theLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
            theLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

and an example view controller showing how to implement that:

```
class ScrollViewExampleVC: UIViewController {
    
    var scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    
    // let's define this here, so we can "play with the speed"
    //  to make it easier to see the difference (e.g. the "cells" don't disappear)
    let animDuration: Double = 0.2
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // instead of a collection view with cells,
        //  let's use a stack view with two "cell" views
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        // these are defaults, but just for clarity
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.spacing = 0
        
        let cellA = ViewInsteadOfCell()
        cellA.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        cellA.theLabel.text = "First"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(cellA)
        
        let cellB = ViewInsteadOfCell()
        cellB.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        cellB.theLabel.text = "Second"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(cellB)

        // two buttons for the bottom to switch
        //  between "Left" and "Right"
        var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        
        cfg.title = "First"
        let btnA = UIButton(configuration: cfg)
        btnA.addAction (
            UIAction { _ in
                self.animateToFirstCell()
            }, for: .touchUpInside
        )
        
        cfg.title = "Second"
        let btnB = UIButton(configuration: cfg)
        btnB.addAction (
            UIAction { _ in
                self.animateToSecondCell()
            }, for: .touchUpInside
        )
        
        // don't let buttons expand vertically
        btnA.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        btnB.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        btnA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btnA)

        btnB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btnB)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // buttons at the bottom
            btnA.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            btnA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            btnB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            btnB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            btnB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnA.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            btnB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnA.widthAnchor),
            
            // scroll view top/leading/trailing to view safe area
            //  bottom to top of buttons
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnA.topAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // stack view constrained all four sides to scroll view's Content Layout Guide
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor),
            
            // stack view height equal to scroll view Frame Layout Guide height
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.heightAnchor),
            // stack view width equal to scroll view Frame Layout Guide width * 2
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2.0),
            
        ])
    }
    
    func animateToFirstCell() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animDuration, animations: {
            self.scrollView.setContentOffset(.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), animated: false)
        })
    }
    func animateToSecondCell() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animDuration, animations: {
            self.scrollView.setContentOffset(.init(x: self.scrollView.frame.width, y: 0.0), animated: false)
        })
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion to use a scroll view is a good idea. At the moment I am not sure what the benefits or downsides are when using scroll view (besides fixing the animation bug). I will think about it. Or if you know already then I would be happy to hear.

The work around with "screenWidth - 1 pixel" trick, I already tried. That worked quite good but when the user changes the cells pretty fast then the animation behaviour becomes a little bit weird. Probably because of the setContentOffset in the completion handler.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. But its great that you also use (and provided) programmatic ui.
I tried the solution with the ScrollView and it worked fine. An additional benefit is that the screens only need to derive from UIView and no longer from UICollectionViewCell.